# Expression type '@lvalue CGFloat' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift

I try to make fade out animation and the code like below.
But I got the error like title, I don't know how to fix it.
Anyone who can help me ?Thx advance!!!

```
private func showAnimation(){
    if self.resultPresent.alpha == 1.0{
          UIView.animate(withDuration: 2,option: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
              self.resultPresent.alpha = CGFloat(0)→Expression type '@lvalue CGFloat' is ambiguous without more context
          })
      }
}
```

Comment: directly use  `self.resultPresent.alpha = 0`

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya it shows the same error so I tried above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use following code.The parameters to the functions you are using seems to have changed

```
 private func showAnimation()
    {
    if self.resultPresent.alpha == 1.0
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.resultPresent.alpha = 1.0 // Final value of alpha
        }, completion: nil)
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no version of `UIView.animate` with the parameters you're using.

Try this instead:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
    self.resultPresent.alpha = 0
})
```

or, this shorter form that uses `.curveEaseInOut` by default:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
    self.resultPresent.alpha = 0
})
```